# Screen recording software with internal recording on android

Tags: android, screen-recording

Software recommendation screen recording which supports internal audio recording, I have used recme before but it's really unstable it works for some time and stops working
and while its recording I can't hear audio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Samsung device your in luck Instead of downloading software's like recme etc.which requires device to be rooted.

We directly use the gaming tools which doesn't require root ,it can be activated in setting under advanced features,

## Configure Gaming tools to record screen with internal audio

- once you have activated gaming tools open game launcher app
- in that add an app of your choice
- after adding ,goto your application where want to screen record
- When you open the application you'll find small icon flashing near left corner
- click on the icon and select settings in the menu which appears
- Now click 'Record' which appears in the new menu
- now select audio source as phone audio

Voila your done

P.S android 10 natively supports screen recording with internal audio

For lower versions we need to use above mentioned software